# Moving row to a completely different spreadsheet when checkbox is checked

Tags: checkbox, rows, move

**Hi I have 2 spreadsheets, for example, one is called '*test*' and the other '*test1*'.  I want when checkbox is checked for a row on spreadsheet 'test', the entire row moves to 'test1' spreadsheet.  I used this script and it works perfectly if I want the row to move to another sheet in the 'test' spreadsheet.**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "New" || r.columnStart != 6 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Complete");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,6).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,6));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
 }
```

**But when I change it to this script so the row is moved from 'test' to 'test1' it does not work.  I can't seem to figure out the solution.  Can anyone help - thanks so much!**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "New" || r.columnStart != 6 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet("19D-PzL- 
  YGdRQbXdGeILMeUbHFJkxeMFan0di7eSqK6E").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,6).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,6));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);

}
```